# Transform of the Cartesian plane that maps hyperbolic arcs $xy = C$ to line segments

Tags: transformation, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I have the finite set of curves: $$y = \frac{C}{x}, \qquad C = 2, 3, \ldots, C_{\max},$$ with $C$ and $x$ positive integers, $2 \le x \le C$ ($x$ varies on a finite domain).

Is it possible to apply some transformation to the Cartesian coordinate plane, so that **all** such curves become parallel straight segments?

How would such a transformation be created?

**P.S.**
One thing I forgot to mention: If possible, I would also like all the lines (or segments, more precisely) to have slope $-1$.

Comment: Are you content with a transformation that maps just the first quadrant to the plane (certainly the arcs you mention are all subsets of this quadrant)? If so, applying a logarithmic transformation to both coordinates will do the trick. (If this is sufficient for your needs, I can expand this into a proper answer if you'd like.)

Comment: There are many ways, specially since you didn't put any other requirements to the transformation. For example, you can square the points $(x,y)\mapsto(x^2-y^2,2xy)$. This sends them $(x,C/x)\mapsto (x^2-C^2/x^2,2C)$ to horizontal lines.

Comment: Yes Travis, I would be content with a transformation that maps just the first quadrant to the plane. Please do expand: I would be very happy to see the details :-)

Comment: @Pam Sure, I'll write up an answer now.

Comment: Thank you Alamos: very interesting. One thing I forgot to mention (sorry), I would like all the lines (segments) to have slope -1.

Comment: Then you can square the points, this makes them all horizontal, and then apply a rotation of $-\pi/4$, i.e. $(x,y)\mapsto\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x+y),\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-x+y)\right)$. Composing these two transformations we get $(x,y)\mapsto\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x^2-C^2/x^2)+\sqrt{2}C,-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x^2-C^2/x^2)+\sqrt{2}C\right)$.

Comment: Thank you Alamos. What you suggests holds for each C at a time, or for all the C in the in the set C=2,3,...,Cmax ? (What I am after is a way to have simultaneously, for all the given C values, all the pieces of  hyperbolas to look like straight segments.)

Comment: All the $C$'s. You can see it in the first formula how the second coordinate becomes constant (that is why they become horizontal lines).

Comment: Thanks a lot Alamos: I have to confess I need to play a bit with your transformation with my pc to really "digest" it. In case, I will bother you later with some more questions. Of course, if you wish to expand it in an answer I think it can be also useful to others in the future. For now thanks a lot: very kind and helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way can be to first square the points of the plane:

$$(x,y)\mapsto(x^2-y^2,2xy)$$

This sends the hyperbolas to horizontal lines

$$(x,y)\mapsto(x^2-C^2/x^2,2C)$$

To get the slope that you want we can then rotate the appropriate angle ($-\pi/4$):

$$(x,y)\mapsto\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x+y),\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(-x+y)\right)$$

Composing these two transformations we get:

$$(x,y)\mapsto\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x^2-C^2/x^2+2C),\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(2C-(x^2-C^2/x^2))\right)$$

Comment: This coordinate transformation is especially nice for two reasons: (1) the curves $x^2 - y^2 = a$ and $2xy = b$ corresponding to straight lines in the transformed coordinates are all hyperbolas (or degenerate hyperbolas in the cases $a = 0$ and $b = 0$), and (2) because the transformation arises from the (analytic) complex squaring map $z \mapsto z^2$, the transformation is conformal and so the two families of curves intersect each other orthogonally at every point (except where $(z^2)' = 2z = 0, namely, at the  origin).

Comment: Yes, I have been playing with it a bit so far and you are right: it's pretty interesting. I was wondering where this come from, did you just made it up on the spot, or this transformation has a "name" and arises in some context. Also, another thing I was wondering if this is easily invertible (get back the original coordinates). Any idea of what the inverse formulas would look like ?

Comment: @Pam The first one is just the square function $z\mapsto z^2$ where the multiplication is the multiplication of points on the plane, improperly called complex multiplication, or multiplication of complex number. The second is rotation of an angle $-\pi/4$, or if you want, can also be seen as multiplication by the point $e^{-\pi i/4}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$. Another way to write it is $z\mapsto e^{-\pi i/4}z^2$. You can define an "inverse" $w\mapsto \sqrt{e^{\pi i/4}w}$.

Comment: @Pam I just wanted to first "open" the right angle of the first quadrant, and the square function on the plane does that: it opens the right angle into a straight angle. When you write the effect for the hyperbolas you see they get straightened too. The rotation is there only because you wanted lines with slope $-1$.

Comment: I really like this transformation. I also like the rotation, as it somehow makes the transform more "symmetrically distributed" across the coordinates, if I can say so (not sure if there is a proper way to express that). In case later you have some spare time, would you mind to add in your great answer the inverse formulas too in an "explicit" form (like the other formulas), in addition to the interesting and compact "complex" notation you just used)? I'd like to code them in my computer to see them at work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Rearranging gives the equations $$xy = C, \qquad x > 0,$$ defining the branch of the given hyperbolae $y = \frac{C}{x}$ in the (since $C > 0$) find quadrant. We'll give two sets of coordinates well-adapted to the geometry of the hyperbolae (in particular, in which they are represented by straight lines).

Taking the logarithm of both sides of our equations gives for each hyperbola that
$$\log x + \log y = \log C,$$
so in the naive coordinates $(s, t)$ defined by $$s := \log x, \quad t := \log y,$$ these hyperbolae have the simple form
$$s + t = \log C.$$
This equation is affine in $s, t$, and in these coordinates the hyperbolae (or rather, the branches of the hyperbolae in the first quadrant) are lines with slope $-1$ as desired, and hence are all parallel.

**Remark** One can also define the so-called 
[**hyperbolic coordinates**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_coordinates): Via the slightly more sophisticated coordinate transformation
$$u := \frac{1}{2}\log \frac{x}{y}, \quad v := \sqrt{xy},$$
the hyperbola $xy = C$ corresponds to the vertical line $v = \sqrt{C}$, as for the previous transformation, these lines are all parallel.